# The css blurs the box border in chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome

[image]

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
p {
  column-fill: balance;
  column-count: 2;
}

.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  filter: blur(5px);
  z-index: -1;
  animation: move 15s linear infinite;
}
.box2 {
  position: relative;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
.box2::before {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  top: -0px;
  left: -0px;
  bottom: -0px;
  right: -0px;
  background-image: conic-gradient(
    from 36deg at 20% 80%,
    #a100ffff 0% 25%,
    #000000 25% 30%,
    #119cfdff 30% 50%
  );

  filter: blur(500px);
  z-index: -1;
  animation: move 15s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes move {
  from {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }

  to {
    transform: rotate(540deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script src="src/index.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="src/styles.css" />
    <div>
      <div class="box">1<br />12</div>
      <div class="box2">1<br />12</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

It should look like Firefox on the far left, but lately, it's showing strange wireframes. Yes, that wasn't the case a while ago .

I put the code codesandbox to replicate the effect

[https://codesandbox.io/](https://codesandbox.io/embed/jssandbox-forked-4r9tz8?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

It should look like Firefox on the far left

Comment: Did you upload the correct image? The image and the codesandbox look totally different.

Comment: image is screenshot of the project.The problem is repeated in codesandbox

Comment: A proper [mre] of your issue belongs directly into your question; please do not just send us to external platforms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can force activate hardware acceleration by using 3d transforms to get rid of the visual artifact:

```css
transform: rotate3D(0, 0, 1, 180deg);
```

Not sure why it happens on Chrome, must be a bug that introduced recently.

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
p {
  column-fill: balance;
  column-count: 2;
}

.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  filter: blur(5px);
  z-index: -1;
  animation: move 15s linear infinite;
}
.box2 {
  position: relative;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
.box2::before {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  top: -0px;
  left: -0px;
  bottom: -0px;
  right: -0px;
  background-image: conic-gradient(
    from 36deg at 20% 80%,
    #a100ffff 0% 25%,
    #000000 25.5% 30%,
    #119cfdff 30.5% 50%
  );

  filter: blur(500px);
  background-color: white;
  z-index: -1;
  animation: move 15s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes move {
  from {
    transform: rotate3D(0, 0, 1, 180deg);
  }

  to {
    transform: rotate3D(0, 0, 1, 540deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script src="src/index.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="src/styles.css" />
    <div>
      <div class="box">1<br />12</div>
      <div class="box2">1<br />12</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```