# Blurred div element creating grid like appearance

Tags: html, css

I have added `div`s with the following styling to create an ambient background for my page:

```
// tailwind css
<div className="relative z-0 -mb-36 rounded-full blur-[128px] opacity-100 w-48 h-48 bg-blue-500 top-20 -left-10" />
<div className="relative z-0 -mb-36 rounded-full blur-[96px] opacity-75 w-36 h-48 bg-purple-300 top-20 left-40" />
```

But upon render, they create these grid-like appearance with sharp edges such as:
[image]

Is there a trick to smoothen out these edges upon rendering? Or am I doing something completely wrong to begin with? Maybe the blur value is just too high?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The css blurs the box border in chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77471538/the-css-blurs-the-box-border-in-chrome)

Comment: @HaoWu I don't think that is the same issue as mine

Comment: @Choice I think it IS the same issue

Comment: I assume that you're using React and Tailwind. If so, tag it accordingly and mention it in the description...